# No can do-its structure and origin

Tags: idioms

Teddy asks her brother to turn the music down, but his brother says:

> **No can do**, sis.

What is the structure of "no can do"? Is it a short form of something? like, "No, I can't do it"?

Comment: Betting it's a "softer" version of "NO GO" from military use.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go/no_go

Comment: It's colloquial for: I cannot do that.

Comment: [Answerable with a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20can%20do)

Answer (score 2):

"No can do" means that something is not possible, for whatever reasons. It doesn't necessarily mean that something is completely logistically impossible, but perhaps not so by the person being asked or within the suggested timeframe.

"No can do" is listed in some dictionaries as an idiom, but arguably it is also a *compound noun* because we can say something *is* **a** "no-can-do".

Saying something is "a no-can-do" is syntactically similar to expressions like "no-go". They sound like military lingo, or possibly radio (as in 2-way-radio) jargon.